# better way to duplicate a layer using ogr in python?

Tags: shapefile, ogr, fiona

I'm splitting a large shapefile into many smaller ones using ogr.  I'd like to just copy all of the field and layer config information from the original.  Here's how I'm doing it now:

```
src = ogr.Open('original.shp', 0)
layer = src.GetLayerByIndex(0)
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
ds = driver.CreateDataSource('file1.shp')
dest_layer = ds.CreateLayer('layer1',
                            srs = layer.GetSpatialRef(),
                            geom_type=layer.GetLayerDefn().GetGeomType())
feature  = layer.GetFeature(0)
[dest_layer.CreateField(feature.GetFieldDefnRef(i)) for i in range(feature.GetFieldCount())]
```

Is there a more succinct way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [Fiona](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fiona/0.10) of Sean Gillies , a very simple wrapper of the OGR library ([The Fiona User Manual](http://toblerity.github.com/fiona/manual.html))

All the elements of a shapefile (schema, records) are processed using Python dictionaries:

schema of one of my shapefiles as example:

> `{'geometry': 'LineString', 'properties': {u'faille': 'str:20', u'type': 'str:20', u'id': 'int'}}`

one record in the shapefile:

> `{'geometry': {'type': 'LineString', 'coordinates': [(269884.20917418826, 151805.1917153612), (270409.89083992655, 153146.21637285672), (272298.05355768028, 154047.38494269375), (272941.74539327814, 155484.96337552898), (272169.31519056071, 156117.92701386689)]}, 'id': '1',  'properties': {'faille': u'de Salinas', 'type': u'normale'}}`

so to duplicate a shapefile:

```py
from shapely.geometry import mapping, shape
import fiona
# Read the original Shapefile
with fiona.collection('original.shp', 'r') as input:
    # The output has the same schema
    schema = input.schema.copy()
    # write a new shapefile
    with fiona.collection(''file1.shp', 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', schema) as output:
        for elem in input:
             output.write({'properties': elem['properties'],'geometry': mapping(shape(elem['geometry']))})
```

If you want to split a large shapefile into many smaller ones, everything takes place in the for loop but all the schemas of the original shapefile are preserved in the dictionary with `schema = input.schema.copy()` and `{'properties': elem['properties']`

see [How do I find vector line bearing in QGIS or GRASS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55449/how-do-i-find-vector-line-bearing-in-qgis-or-grass/55480#55480) for an example of

1. spliting a shapefile
2. preserve the attributes of the original shapefile in the splitted shapefile
3. and add a new field in the splitted shapefile

For Mac OS X or Linux users, it is easy to install. For Windows users, use the version of  Christoph Gohlke [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#fiona)

Comment: Liked Fiona's simplicity a lot. But I ran into the problem that Fiona 1.6 does not work with GDAL 2. Hopefully they'll be  upgrading that...

Answer (score 0):

For those who struggle to install the libraries above:

```
import shapefile

r = shapefile.Reader('original') # original shp file
w = shapefile.Writer()

w.fields = list(r.fields)
w._shapes.extend(r.shapes()) # copy over geometry without any changes
w.save('new_shp_file')
```