# Calculate azimuth of vector for QGIS 2.0 Python plugin

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I calculate the azimuth of a vector and update a field in my QGIS 2.0 Python 2.7 plugin. This works currently, but it takes much longer than i'd like to. I believe it is because i'm querying the data source on every call. Any suggestions on updating the fields all in one go as was suggested in another one of my [questions?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/64482/speeding-up-a-length-calculation-for-a-qgis-plugin) I'm having issues trying to adapt the suggestion for this particular evaluate function.

```
    self.rotateLayer.startEditing()
    bear_idx = self.rotateLayer.fieldNameIndex('angleRot')
    bearCalc = QgsExpression('(atan((xat(-1)-xat(0))/(yat(-1)-yat(0)))) * 180/3.14159 + (180 *(((yat(-1)-yat(0)) < 0) + (((xat(-1)-xat(0)) < 0 AND (yat(-1) - yat(0)) >0)*2)))')
    bearCalc.prepare(self.rotateLayer.pendingFields())
    for fields in self.rotateLayer.getFeatures():
        fields[bear_idx] = bearCalc.evaluate(fields)
        self.rotateLayer.updateFeature(fields)
    self.rotateLayer.commitChanges()
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what you are trying to do. In PyQGIS, the azimuth of a vector is given by

```
line_start_point.azimuth(line_end_point)
```

Look at [How to add Direction and Distance to attribute table?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24260/how-to-add-direction-and-distance-to-attribute-table/24430#24430), [How do I find vector line bearing in QGIS or GRASS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55449/how-do-i-find-vector-line-bearing-in-qgis-or-grass/55480#55480) or [Create Intersecting lines and remove dangles](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116502/create-intersecting-lines-and-remove-dangles/116751#116751)

Comment: thanks for the tip, i will eventually try to adapt it, as I did not see this before. I'm wondering, though, if  solution would actually help speed things up. My code works--it just takes a long time. Taking a look at the suggestion on "How to add Direction and Distance to the attribute table?", just selecting my thousand vectors would take a while as well.

Comment: With only Python with [Fiona](http://toblerity.github.com/fiona/manual.html), it is much faster.