# Cut a linear feature according to the directions or azimuths

Tags: python, line, shapely, fiona, azimuth

I have a shapefile linear that contains a single items as in the image and I want to divide it into several section respecting the azimuth and the line direction.

[image]

i have this code :

```
    import os
    import fiona
    from shapely.geometry import mapping
    from shapely.geometry import Point,LineString
    import math

    os.chdir('SHP')

    def azimut(point1, point2):
           '''Retourne l'azimuth de la ligne entre 2 points shapely'''
           angle = math.atan2(point2.x - point1.x, point2.y - point1.y)
           return math.degrees(angle)
           print angle
           **if angle &amp;&gt;= 0: else math.degrees(angle) + 180** **Error syntax**


    **def paires(liste):
         '''parcourt une liste par paires'''
         for i in range(1, len(liste)):
             yield liste[i-1], liste[i]**

    with fiona.collection('BOM1.shp', 'r') as entree:
        # copie du schema de la couche et création d'un nouveau champ 'azimut'
        schema = entree.schema.copy()
        schema['properties']['azimut'] = 'int'
        # création d' une nouvelle couche avec le schéma résultant
        with fiona.collection('testligne_azim.shp', 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', schema) as sortie:
            for ligne in entree:
            # utilisation de la fonction paire() pour extraire les segments de lignes
                for seg_start, seg_end in paires(ligne['geometry']['coordinates']):
                    # création d'une ligne en fonction des points des segments
                    line_start =Point(seg_start)
                    line_end = Point(seg_end)
                    segment = LineString([line_start.coords[0],line_end.coords[0]])
                    # copie des attributs d'entrée et ajout de la valeur résultante
                    # de la fonction azimut()
                    elem = {}                  
                    elem['properties'] = ligne['properties'] 
                    elem['properties']['azimut'] = azimut(line_start, line_end)
                    elem['geometry'] = mapping(segment)
                    sortie.write(elem)
```

but the problem is in :

```
if angle &amp;&gt;= 0: else math.degrees(angle) + 180
```

i have syntax error **angle &>= 0**

and in:

```
def paires(liste):
         '''parcourt une liste par paires'''
         for i in range(1, len(liste)):
             yield liste[i-1], liste[i]
```

i have this error **position 29: ordinal not in range(128)**

Comment: why `&amp;&gt;=` instead of `>=` and does `angle` contains non-ascii char (e.g. degree symbol)?

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple transliteration (HTML) error ("`&amp;&gt;`" = > in HTML).
The script comes from [Python: traitement des couches vectorielles dans une perspective géologique, lecture et enregistrement des couches sous forme de dictionnaires avec le module Fiona](http://www.portailsig.org/content/python-traitement-des-couches-vectorielles-dans-une-perspective-geologique-lecture-et-enregi) and the complete code in English is given in [How do I find vector line bearing in QGIS or GRASS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/55480)

```
 def azimuth(point1, point2):
   '''azimuth between 2 shapely points (interval 0 - 180°, for my work)'''
   angle = math.atan2(point2.x - point1.x, point2.y - point1.y)
   return math.degrees(angle)if angle>0 else math.degrees(angle) + 180

def pair(list):
   '''Iterate over pairs in a list '''
    for i in range(1, len(list)):
        yield list[i-1], list[i]
```

The second function (`def pair(list)`) is a simple Python generator that is not the cause of your error.

Note

Honestly, knowing Python and a few angular rules, it was not too difficult to correct the first function...

You can use `return math.degrees(angle) % 360`