# QGIS - Rotating all symbols to face a single point

Tags: qgis, symbology, angles

I am creating a map with airports, using an airplane symbology (svg).
Instead of having all small plane symbols turned north, I would like to rotate them to be all turned to Paris.
I have 28 airport points in one layer, and the point of Paris in another layer.

I assume I need to draw lines between each point to Paris, then calculate some rotation angle that I can then [use](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216987/rotate-marker-symbols-individually-in-qgis) in the symbology.

How is this best achieved?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am making the following assumptions:

1. You are using a projected coordinate system
2. Your data is in two separate layers called `cities` and `planes`

This solution should also extend to the case of multiple cities

Onto the solution:

1. Add a unique id field to `planes` called `plane_id`
2. Add a unique id field to `cities` called `city_id` (it will just be one value in OP's case, but if you have multiple cities then this solution will extend to that case as well)
3. Add a field to `planes` called `city_id` and set it equal to each plane's corresponding city's `city_id` value from `cities` (in OP's case, this will just be a single value)
4. In the Toolbox, run Join by lines (hub lines), naming the output `spokes` with the following inputs:

   - Hub layer: `cities`
   - Hub id field: `city_id`
   - Spoke layer: `planes`
   - Spoke id field: `city_id` (This is actually where you determine to which hub each spoke will be connected to, not the unique id field of each spoke)
5. Add a real/float/double field to `spokes` called `angle` and set it equal to `angle_at_vertex(geometry:=$geometry,vertex:=0)` ([Source](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314016/calculating-bearing-of-polyline-in-qgis))
6. Join `spokes` to `planes` using the field `plane_id` for both layers
7. (Optional) Save `planes` as a new layer if you want to preserve the join
8. Set the rotation angle of the `planes` symbol to the angle field which was just joined into plane (see pic)

[image]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

**A one-step scenario** :

you add a virtual field in your **airports** table using the following expression :

`angle_at_vertex( make_line( centroid($geometry), centroid( geometry( get_feature( 'destinations', 'name', 'PARIS')))), 0)`

And you use that angle value ("angle") as **data-defined rotation** as mentionned by @wfgeo

I assume your "PARIS" point layer is called 'destinations' and has a 'name' attribute.