# How to create a line from more than two points?

Tags: qgis, python

I have a loop which calculates two points for each iteration (x3,y3) and (x4,y4). As seen in the code these two points are added for each iteration, which gives i-1 lines. Each line has a individual id.

What I want is to add all these points at the same time, so it makes **one polyline** with only one id. This is done by adding all the points in the line:

```
fet.setGeometry( QgsGeometry.fromMultiPolyline([[QgsPoint(x3,y3), QgsPoint(x4,y4)]]))
```

instead of only these two points at the time. But I can not figure out how to change the loop to make it work. I guess for each iteration, I have to save a string with QgsPoint(x3,y3), QgsPoint(x4,y4) for the given iteration and add the next two points as a string in the next iteration. But I can not see how?

```
for i in range(0,len(points)-1):
    coor1 = points[i]
    x1 = coor1[0]
    y1 = coor1[1]
    dist = 0
    coor2 = points[i+1]
    x2 = coor2[0]
    y2 = coor2[1]
    dn = ((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y1)**2)**0.5
    x3 = x1 + dist*(y1-y2) / dn
    y3 = y1 - dist*(x1-x2) / dn     
    x4 = x2 + dist*(y1-y2) / dn
    y4 = y2 - dist*(x1-x2) / dn  

    fet.setGeometry( QgsGeometry.fromMultiPolyline([[QgsPoint(x3,y3), QgsPoint(x4,y4)]]))
    pr.addFeatures( [ fet ] )
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you need to do a bit more please?  Do you want to build out a polygon as you go though each iteration?

Comment: Yes, I want to build a polyline with only one id. The polyline should contain all x3,y3 and x4,y4 for all i.

Answer (score 2):

use a Python iterator. See   [How to calculate distances in a point sequence?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44064/how-to-calculate-distances-in-a-point-sequence/56589#56589)  or   [How do I find vector line bearing in QGIS or GRASS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55449/how-do-i-find-vector-line-bearing-in-qgis-or-grass/55480#55480)

example (iterator from [Most pythonic way to get the previous element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076270/most-pythonic-way-to-get-the-previous-element/12076386#12076386)):

```py
# iterator 
def pair_points(iterable):
    prev = None
    for elem in iterable:
        yield prev, elem
        prev = elem
```

Application with a simple example:

```
points = ((1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8))
for pt in pair_points(points):
    print pt
 (None, (1, 2))
 ((1, 2), (3, 4))
 ((3, 4), (5, 6))
 ((5, 6), (7, 8))
```

So, to avoid the None

```
for i, pair in enumerate(pair_points(points)):
    if i > 0: # None
        print pair
 ((1, 2), (3, 4))
 ((3, 4), (5, 6))
 ((5, 6), (7, 8))
```

and in your case:

```
def new_point(point1,point2):
   dist = 0
   x1,y1 = point1
   x2,y2 = point2
   dn = ((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y1)**2)**0.5
   x3 = x1 + dist*(y1-y2) / dn
   y3 = y1 - dist*(x1-x2) / dn     
   x4 = x2 + dist*(y1-y2) / dn
   y4 = y2 - dist*(x1-x2) / dn
   return x3,y3,x4,y4    

for i, pair in enumerate(pair_points(points)):
    if i > 0:
       x3,y3, x4,y4 = new_point(pair[0],pair[1])
       fet.setGeometry( QgsGeometry.fromMultiPolyline([[QgsPoint(x3,y3), QgsPoint(x4,y4)]]))
       pr.addFeatures( [ fet ] )
```

But I don't understand the dist = 0 because:

```
x3 = x1 + dist*(y1-y2) / dn = x1 /dn
```

Comment: You can even do: https://gist.github.com/NathanW2/5284046 with the x3, y3, etc lines.  Just for a bit of clean up.

Comment: yes but with dist = 0 it is the same as x3, y3, x4, y4 = (x1 / dn, y1 / dn, x2/ dn, y2/ dn)

Comment: true even better :)

Answer (score 0):

The dist is not zero, I just forgot to give it a number. The example you give works, but it does not do what I want. What I want is to get the following line:

```
fet.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromMultiPolyline([[QgsPoint(x3,y3), QgsPoint(x4,y4), Qgspoint(x3,y3), QgsPoint(x4,y4), Qgs...)]]))
```

I want only one setGeometry line with all the x3,y3 and x4,y4 generated for each i. So all these lines have the same id. I hope it makes sense. It is my first python code, and are soooo close to make it work :D

Another possibility maybe is to this for each single point:

```
 fet.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(x3,y3))
 pr.addFeatures( [ fet ] )
```

and afterwards convert this to a polyline. But I do not know if that can be done.