# How to calculate distance in meter between QgsPoint objects in PyQgis?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I tried to calculate distance between QgsPoint objects in qgis, i used QgsPoint `StartPoint.sqrDist(EndPoint)`.

but i don't find an expected result, i also tried

```
import math
math.sqrt(StartPoint.sqrDist(EndPoint))
```

but still getting a very high result.
does somebody know a way how to calculate distance in meter between 2 Qgspoint objects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a simple geometry problem, not a PyQGIS problem.

If the unit of the projection system is meter, according to the Euclidean distance formula, the distance between two points in the plane is given by:

```
def euclidean_distance(point1,point2):
    return math.sqrt((point2.x()-point1.x())**2 + (point2.y()-point1.y())**2)
pt1 = QgsPoint(50,50)
pt2 = QgsPoint(150,150)
print euclidean_distance(pt1,pt2)
141.42135623730951
```

Using `sqrDist`, the square distance between the two points:

```
def qgisdist(point1,point2):
     return math.sqrt(point1.sqrDist(point2))
print qgisdist(pt1,pt2)
141.42135623730951
```

So the result is the Euclidean Distance and, if the unit is not meter, you cannot use `sqrDist`.

You need to use other distances as the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) (look at [QGIS - How to calculate distances in a point sequence?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44064/how-to-calculate-distances-in-a-point-sequence/56589#56589))

The solution of Nathan W is to change the projection with PyQGIS2.

Comment: i tried QgsGeometry().fromPoint(EndPoint).distance(QgsGeometry().fromPoint(StPoint))

Comment: It is also the Euclidean Distance: `QgsGeometry().fromPoint(pt1t).distance(QgsGeometry().fromPoint(pt2))` = 141.42135623730951

Answer (score 7):

You need a `QgsDistanceArea` object:

```
self.distancearea = QgsDistanceArea()
self.distancearea.setSourceCrs( self.canvas.mapRenderer().destinationCrs().srsid())
ellispoid = QgsProject.instance().readEntry("Measure", "/Ellipsoid", GEO_NONE)
self.distancearea.setEllipsoid(ellispoid[0])
mode = self.canvas.mapRenderer().hasCrsTransformEnabled()
self.distancearea.setEllipsoidalMode(ellispoidemode)

distance = self.distancearea.measureLine( start, end)
```

Comment: i had a python error AttributeError: 'QgsDistanceArea' object has no attribute 'setEllipsoidalMode', i'm in qgis 1.8