# Measuring distances from each pixel center (in raster) to each point (in vector) in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, point, distance, pixel

I have one raster layer and point vector layer. I want to measure distance between center of each pixel in raster to each point in vector layer. I extracted x,y center of each cell and added them to a list, but I can't make a relation between this list and vector points to calculate distances. How can I measure distances?

```
from qgis.core import *
from osgeo import gdal, ogr, osr

pntLayer = QgsVectorLayer("/Data/Villages.shp","pointLayer")

feat = [ feat for feat in pntLayer.getFeatures() ]

# Open tif file
ds = QgsRasterLayer("/Data/Study.tif","Study")

pixelWidth = ds.rasterUnitsPerPixelX()
pixelHeight = ds.rasterUnitsPerPixelY()

# extent of the layer
ext = ds.extent()

originX ,originY = (ext.xMinimum(),ext.yMinimum())
src_cols = ds.width()
src_rows = ds.height()

outDs = drive.Create("/Data/pop_Rst.tif", src_cols, src_rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
outBand = outDs.GetRasterBand(1)

outData = numpy.zeros((src_cols, src_rows), numpy.float32)

def pixel2coord(x, y):
    xp = (pixelWidth * x) + originX + (pixelWidth/2)
    yp = (pixelHeight * y) + originY + (pixelHeight /2)
    return(xp, yp)

pntRstList = []

for i in range(0, src_cols):
    for j in range(0, src_rows):
        rspnt = pixel2coord(i,j)
        pntRstList.append(rspnt)

print pntRstList
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this question, [How to calculate distance in meter between QgsPoint objects in PyQgis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94177/how-to-calculate-distance-in-meter-between-qgspoint-objects-in-pyqgis), it's easy.

You just need to return a QgsPoint with your function pixel2coord() :

```
def pixel2coord(x, y):
    xp = (pixelWidth * x) + originX + (pixelWidth/2)
    yp = (pixelHeight * y) + originY + (pixelHeight /2)
    pnt = QgsPoint(xp, yp)
    return pnt
```

Then you will store a list of QgsPoint than you can compare to your vector Point (store in your feat list) like that:

```
for vpoint in feat :
    for rpoint in pntRstList:
        vgeometry = QgsGeometry().fromPoint(vpoint) 
        rgeometry = QgsGeometry().fromPoi‌​nt(rpoint)
        dist=vgeometry.distance(rgeometry)
```

I'm not sure it's the most efficient way to do this but it should works.

Comment: Hi @YoLecomte, Thanks for answer, but I receive "invalid syntax" in last line "distance=QgsGeometry().fromPoint(vpoint).distance(QgsGeometry().fromPoi‌​nt(rpoint))".

Comment: @nikan I would suggest not using a method as a variable name because may confuses QGIS. Try using `dist` as a variable, for example.

Comment: Hi @mgri, I used dist as a variable but It didn't solved.

Comment: @nikan I've edited my answer, I test the new code in QGIS python console and it works well.

Comment: @YoLecomte, I think there is a problem in pntRstList because in your edited code I again receive invalid syntax in "rgeometry = QgsGeometry().fromPoi‌​nt(rpoint)" in QGIS python.

Comment: @nikan my comment was not to be intended as a solution, but as a suggestion. However, does it change something if you use `pntRstList.append(QgsPoint(rspnt))` instead of what you provided?

Comment: @nikan What is stored in pntRstList? Can you print it?

Comment: @mgri, thanks for your comment. Sorry it is not worked for: pntRstList.append(QgsPoint(rspnt))

Comment: @YoLecomte, yes I can print it. It is a list of pair x, y center of each cell in raster layer.

Comment: @nikan ok that's probably why it doesn't works... You need a list of QgsPoint. I have edited my answer to store the point in a variable and return this variable. It works for me in python console.

Answer (score 3):

There were some missing pieces of code. I used the solution by [@YoLecomte](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/246604/87487) for obtaining a working solution:

```
from qgis.core import *
from osgeo import gdal, ogr, osr
import numpy

def pixel2coord(x, y):
    xp = (pixelWidth * x) + originX + (pixelWidth/2)
    yp = (pixelHeight * y) + originY + (pixelHeight /2)
    return QgsPoint(xp, yp)

pntLayer = QgsVectorLayer("/Data/Villages.shp","pointLayer",'ogr')

feats = [ feat for feat in pntLayer.getFeatures() ]

# Open tif file
ds = QgsRasterLayer("/Data/Study.tif","Study")

pixelWidth = ds.rasterUnitsPerPixelX()
pixelHeight = ds.rasterUnitsPerPixelY()

# extent of the layer
ext = ds.extent()

originX ,originY = (ext.xMinimum(),ext.yMinimum())
src_cols = ds.width()
src_rows = ds.height()
drive = gdal.GetDriverByName( 'GTiff' )
outDs = drive.Create("/Data/pop_Rst.tif", src_cols, src_rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32) # ?
src_ds = gdal.Open( "/Data/Study.tif")
outBand = src_ds.GetRasterBand(1)

outData = numpy.zeros((src_cols, src_rows), numpy.float32)

pntRstList = []

for i in range(0, src_cols):
    for j in range(0, src_rows):
        rspnt = pixel2coord(i,j)
        pntRstList.append(rspnt)

#print pntRstList

for ft in feats:
    vgeometry = ft.geometry()
    for rpoint in pntRstList:
        rgeometry = QgsGeometry.fromPoint(rpoint)
        dist=vgeometry.distance(rgeometry)
        #print dist
```

If it works also for you, please accept the solution by [@YoLecomte](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/98611/yolecomte) since I simply merged his code with yours.

Comment: It's work, That's great job.

Comment: Great! I understand now... I miss to get the geometry of the vector point before calculating the distance...