# Creating raster layer from dictionary in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, rasterization, dictionary

In a dictionary such as below, I have a series of x,y coordinates as key and distance measured as values in dictionary.

I want to convert this dictionary to a raster layer with PyQGIS, Can I do it?

dictionary example:

> mergeDict = {(231111,3.709e+06): 0,
>   (231611,3.7085e+06): 0,
>   (231611,3.7088e+06): [129.4689990991847],
>   (232111,3.7093e+06): [230.72989620660874],
>   (231011,3.7095e+06): 0,
>   (231711,3.7088e+06): [56.121848744267226],
>   (231211,3.7086e+06): 0,
>   (231611,3.709e+06): [126.10543581749376],
>   (231111,3.7093e+06): 0,
>   (231411,3.7096e+06): [88.44457301849167],
>   (232311,3.7096e+06): 0,
>   (232211,3.7087e+06): 0,
>   (231411,3.7089e+06): [147.3714773298335],
>   (231511,3.7093e+06): [84.42704048812357],
>   (231311,3.7094e+06): [91.15471831360921],
>   (231411,3.7087e+06): [126.00603268731915],
>   (231411,3.7094e+06): [96.62363082268323],
>   (231711,3.7091e+06): 0,
>   (231811,3.7089e+06): [55.93565232902348],...}

I tried to create an empty raster then disaggregate x, y coordinates and values by below code but I don't know how to add this data to raster layer.

```
outDs = drive.Create("/Data/aaSamplePop1.tif", src_cols, src_rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
outBand = outDs.GetRasterBand(1)

outData = numpy.zeros((src_cols, src_rows), numpy.float32)

for i in mergeDict.keys():
    for k, j in itertools.combinations(i, 2):
        print k, j
```

Comment: Hi, have a look at this: https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html#create-raster-from-array

Comment: Hi @nickves, thanks for your attention, yes I saw it, my first problem is to extract x, y coordinate and values from dictionary. I can do it by two order, (1) "for i in mergeDict.keys():
    for k, j in itertools.combinations(i, 2):
        print k, j"  (2) "for v in mergeDict.values(): print v"  while I need extract them in one order and then convert them raster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said before related to dictionaries, they don't preserve order as lists and it is necessary to be careful to order data adequately for avoiding errors. However, it's also necessary that points are regularly spaced and form a complete set as in my next example code. In this case, you can get a memory point layer and rasterize it for its values extracted by using **grass:v.to.rast.attribute** method from processing tools. Complete code is:

```
import processing

mergeDict = {(355008,4.47339e+06):0, (355008,4.47332e+06):0, 
             (355008,4.47324e+06):[129.4689990991847], (355008,4.47317e+06):[230.72989620660874], 
             (355008,4.4731e+06):0,  (355008,4.47302e+06):[56.121848744267226], 
             (355082,4.47339e+06):0, (355082,4.47332e+06):[230.72989620660874], 
             (355082,4.47324e+06):0, (355082,4.47317e+06):[88.44457301849167], 
             (355082,4.4731e+06):0,  (355082,4.47302e+06):0, 
             (355156,4.47339e+06):[147.3714773298335], (355156,4.47332e+06):[84.42704048812357], 
             (355156,4.47324e+06):[91.15471831360921], (355156,4.47317e+06):[126.00603268731915], 
             (355156,4.4731e+06):[96.62363082268323],  (355156,4.47302e+06):0, 
             (355230,4.47339e+06):[55.93565232902348], (355230,4.47332e+06):0, 
             (355230,4.47324e+06):0, (355230,4.47317e+06):0, 
             (355230,4.4731e+06):[91.15471831360921],  (355230,4.47302e+06):0, 
             (355304,4.47339e+06):0, (355304,4.47332e+06):[230.72989620660874], 
             (355304,4.47324e+06):0, (355304,4.47317e+06):0, 
             (355304,4.4731e+06):0, (355304,4.47302e+06):[126.10543581749376]}

mergeList = [ [ point, mergeDict[point] ] for point in mergeDict ]

points = [ QgsPoint(item[0][0], item[0][1]) for item in mergeList ]
values = [ item[1] for item in mergeList ]

new_values = []

for item in values:
    if type(item) == list:
        new_values.append(item[0])
    else:
        new_values.append(item)

epsg = 32612

uri = "Point?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer&field=value:real""&index=yes"

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,
                          'points',
                          'memory')

prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

feats = [ QgsFeature() for i in range(len(points)) ]

for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
    feat.setAttributes([i, new_values[i]])
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(points[i]))

prov.addFeatures(feats)

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)

xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = mem_layer.extent().toRectF().getCoords()

TYPE = 1
HSPACING = 73.9887
VSPACING = 73.9887

extent = str(xmin - HSPACING/2)+ ',' + str(xmax + HSPACING/2)+ ',' +str(ymin - VSPACING/2)+ ',' +str(ymax + VSPACING/2) 

path = processing.runalg('grass:v.to.rast.attribute', 
                         mem_layer, #input <ParameterVector>
                         0,         #use <ParameterSelection> 0 for attribute
                         'value',   #column <parameters from input>
                         extent,    #GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER <ParameterExtent>
                         HSPACING,  #GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER <ParameterNumber>
                         0,         #GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER <ParameterNumber>
                         0,         #GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER <ParameterNumber>
                         None)      #output <OutputRaster>

raster = QgsRasterLayer(path['output'],
                        'raster_points')

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(raster)
```

After running it at the Python Console I got:

[image]

where it can be also observed points that were rasterized in this complete process. I hope that it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In my result there is not any raster layer for output in TOC of QGIS.

Comment: This is incomplete and not using raster data but vector points anyways.