# Measuring distances worldwide with QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, distance

I know this was already discussed in other questions, but I feel I have to ask again. 
I have a point layer (locations) and a line layer (electricity grid) which cover the whole world. I have tried using more than one projection (azymuthal, world mercator) but the results weren't good. Is there any possibility to measure point-to-line distances more or less accurately for the whole world? (the accuracy doesn't need to be 100%).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to use `EPSG:4326` and compute the lengths using the [haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) directly from latitudes and longitudes

[image]

the answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/94178/51511) may be useful