# Calculating distance between latitude and longitude points using python

Tags: python, shapefile, cartography, pyqgis

I have a database of 2000 points, which is in CSV format containing latitude and longitude. I want to find the distance between all these points, and then show these points in a map by using pyQGIS; I have seen one example using Fiona but I want to do this in pyQGIS.

I have used following code:

```
def offset(iterable):
    prev = None
    for elem in iterable:
        yield prev, elem
        prev = elem

import csv
import math

def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees).
    Source: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/56589/15183
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(math.radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = math.sin(dlat/2)**2 + math.cos(lat1) * math.cos(lat2) * math.sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * math.asin(math.sqrt(a)) 
    km = 6367 * c
    return km

    with open('1.csv', 'rb') as f1:
    reader1 = csv.reader(f1)
    header1 = reader1.next()
    with open('2.csv', 'rb') as f2:
        reader2 = csv.reader(f2)
        header2 = reader2.next()
        for row1 in offset(header1):
            for row2 in offset(header2):
                floats1 = map(float, row1[1:])
                floats2 = map(float, row2[1:])
                print(floats1)
                print(floats2)
                print haversine(floats1[1],floats1[0],floats2[1],floats2[0])
```

Showing error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 13, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

My .csv file contains following data with about 2000 data pointt:

```
ID  LAT         LONG
1   12.953578   77.592453
2   12.953511   77.592445
3   12.953145   77.593147
4   12.951835   77.594612
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

pseudocode for your problem would be:

```
for point1 in csv:
  for point2 in csv:
    distance = haversine(point1, point2)
```

where haversine is defined as (from e.g. https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/56589/15183) :

```
def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees).
    Source: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/56589/15183
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(math.radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = math.sin(dlat/2)**2 + math.cos(lat1) * math.cos(lat2) * math.sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * math.asin(math.sqrt(a)) 
    km = 6367 * c
    return km
```

...so the full code would be:

```
import csv
import math

def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees).
    Source: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/56589/15183
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(math.radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = math.sin(dlat/2)**2 + math.cos(lat1) * math.cos(lat2) * math.sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * math.asin(math.sqrt(a)) 
    km = 6367 * c
    return km

with open('1.csv', 'rb') as f1:
    reader1 = csv.reader(f1, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    header1 = reader1.next()
    with open('2.csv', 'rb') as f2:
        reader2 = csv.reader(f2, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
        header2 = reader2.next()
        for row1 in reader1:
            for row2 in reader2:
                floats1 = map(float, row1[1:])
                floats2 = map(float, row2[1:])
                print(floats1)
                print(floats2)
                print haversine(floats1[1],floats1[0],floats2[1],floats2[0])
```

with the two files 1.csv:

```
name;lat;lon
NYC;40.58;-74.03
```

and 2.csv:

```
name;lat;lon
Cape Town;-33.90;18.46
```

...result checked against http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html seems correct.

Comment: I am new to python and QGIS. I don't want Fiona. I need only pyqgis to calculate distance between points by importing csv. And also I want to calculate 2000 points of lat & long, distance all at once.

Comment: Earth radius should be 6371