# How to calculate the distance and Azimuth from Point A to Point B in QGIS

Tags: qgis, distance, azimuth

[image: Excel sheet]

Looking to add the Distance and the Azimuth from SPLat/SPLong and to EPLat/SPLong Points. Is there an easy way to do this in QGIS.

Comment: Look here for formulas using Python:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44064/how-to-calculate-distances-in-a-point-sequence

Comment: the format is Excel for the Mac

Comment: I assume what you want to do is : https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html?highlight=azimuth#azimuth  ??

Answer (score 1):

1. Save your Excel file in csv format and load it to QGIS using `Data Source Manager > Delimited Text`. For `Geometry Definition`, you can

   - either simply choose `No geometry (attribute table only)`
   - or use Point Coordinates based on `SPLong` and `SPLat` fields (in case you want to see the points on the map canvas). As your coordinate values are in degrees (lat/lon), be sure to have selected `EPSG:4326` as `Geometry CRS` for the imported points. For `X field` select `SPLong`, for `Y field` use `SPLat`.

   To be able to save the values calculated in the next steps, export the table to a format that can be edited in QGIS like Geopackage.
2. In the attribute table, calculate the length of the line using [Field calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator) with the following expression that generates a new attribute for the length. You must change the CRS used for calclulation to a projected CRS - here I used EPSG:7405, British national grid. Change this accordingly.

   ```
   length (
      transform(
          make_line (
              make_point ( "SPLong" , "SPLat" ),
              make_point ( "EPLong" , "EPLat" )
          ),
      'EPSG:4326',
      'EPSG:7405'  -- change this to a CRS appropriate for measurements in your area of interest
      )
   )
   ```
3. To calculate azimuth, use this expression:

   ```
   degrees(    
       azimuth(
           make_point ( "SPLong" , "SPLat" ),
           make_point ( "EPLong" , "EPLat" )
       )
   )
   ```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest one that works for newbies is the suggestion to do in Excel.
Thanks to Chris Veness and his brilliant VBAs I have solved my own issues...

I find this problem is easiest to solve by working in a spreadsheet, not using the GIS.

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: Link-only answers are problematical, since links fail over time. You need enough content to make the Answer standalone.